# Calculating minimal voxel size in a mesh

Tags: mesh, voxelization

I am developing a script that will determine a minimal voxel size in a mesh. My first thought was to caculate the area of given face. Another approach would be to calculate minimal line length and maximum curvature, but I'm unsure what to do after that.
I couldn't find anything related to that online. I was hoping someone will point me in te right direction.

Comment: Can you describe the problem a little bit more? I am not sure if I am understanding you correctly. Do you want to take an arbitrary 3d mesh and approximate it with voxels?

Comment: Yes. I want to calculate minimal voxel size, as to not lose any details in the mesh